# Do American people say “the office building has five floors”, "It's five-floor building" and “my office is on the fifth story”?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, american-english, british-english

I have done some study and it seems that British **people are fine** with these sentences as they use "**storey/story**" and "**floor**" interchangebly:

"The office building has 5 stories",

"The office building has 5 floors",

"It's a 5-story building",

"It's 5-floor building",

"My office is on the 5th floor" and

"My office is on the 5th story"

However, American people seems to use "**story**" to describe the level of a building and use "**floor**" to describe something is there.

So American people will say

"The office building has 5 stories",

"It's a 5-story building", and

"My office is on the 5th floor"

But they won't say

"The office building has 5 floors",

"It's 5-floor building", and

"My office is on the 5th story".

> And [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/storey?q=storey) (A British dictionary) says
>
> **storey / floor**
>
> You use **storey** (British English)/story (US English) mainly when
> you are talking about the number of levels a building has:
>
> a five-storey house
>
> The office building is five storeys high.
>
> **Floor** is used mainly to talk about which particular level in the building someone lives on, goes to, etc:
>
> His office is on the fifth floor.

So, I think some British people use **storey / floor** separately like the dictionary says but some British use them interchangeably.

Comment: Your research is incorrect. (Americans certainly say "the office building has 5 floors", for example.) Can you please explain how you arrived at your conclusions?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I asked the same question on Quora and an American person said that. So, some American might use  "story and floor" interchangeably

Comment: Dear Tom, the people on Quora range from ignorant fools to people with much knowledge.

Comment: Note: in Britain, if a building has more than one storey (it has multiple storeys) the ground level floor is called the ground floor, and the one above that is the first floor. In America, the first floor is on the ground level.

Comment: Whether you say *floor* or *story*, it always has to be "**a** five-____ building", because *building* is countable.

Comment: I am American, and I feel like either *floor* or *story* is acceptable in "The building has five ____", but in "This is a five-____ building", I would only ever say *story*.

Comment: I'm British and definitely prefer "This is a five-story building" to "This is a five-floor building". In other contexts, either "story" or "floor" might be OK. One confusion is that "five-story" doesn't normally include basements or other sub-ground levels, while "five-floor" can do (especially talking about shops with 5 sales floors).

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that British English speakers use the word 'floor' more often than the word 'storey', but it is certainly known to us and is used. We are more likely to refer to a building with many levels as a "*multi-storey building*", but still refer to each individual level as a 'floor'.

To the best of my knowledge, American English is much the same. The first thing that came to my mind is the song 'Luka' by American singer Suzanne Vega (*My name is Luka / I live on the second floor*).

Note that British English speakers refer to the bottom floor of any multi-storey building as *the ground floor*, and the next level up is the *first floor*. This means that in a 5-storey building in the UK, there is technically no 5th floor.

Comment: Anecdotally, I agree from the American perspective. "I live on the 5th floor" sounds more natural than "I live on the 5th story", though we'd know what you meant (we also, of course, drop the extra vowel, presumably to infuriate the British. Colour -> color, storey -> story). And "5 story building" sounds better than "5 floor building". But to my best recollection, our ground floor is always the same as the 1st floor.